# What does "Package build-essential is virtual" mean? How to solve it?

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation

I have read other posts, most of them were not solved, and I also tried the "solutions" posted there.

I wasn't successful getting a download link by the terminal `apt-get install --print-uris build-essential`

I wasn't successful with `sudo apt-get install build-essential` neither.
I have found an .RPM version of build-essential here. though the steps are not working for me.

2ND question. ----I even tried https://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/build-essential to download directly by AptURL but when I open it, it says "Package build-essential is virtual" What does that mean? Or should I say, how would I resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

The package build-essential is essentially an "Informational list of build-essential packages" rather than an actual package, hence the 'virtual' tag. The details of the most 'essential' of these files can be [seen here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/build-essential) for Trusty Tahr.

A start, if for whatever reason you cannot install the actual 'build-essential' package, would be to run:

```
sudo apt-get install dpkg-dev g++ gcc libc6-dev make
```

And this would provide at least a start for compiling applications...